# How can I show .PARAMETER help messages for dynamic paramters in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I make benefit of lots of dynamic parameters in various modules for many functions.

However, .PARAMETER comment blocks for the dynamic parameters are not shown in get-help.

```
.PARAMETER
Some details of the dynamic parameter that is defined in dynamicParam { block}
```

Is there any work around to provide dynamic parameter details to the user when the get-help cmdlet is called over a such a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get-halfway there if you cheat by duplicating the parameter name with a space after it:

```
param ([string]${Name })

DynamicParam{
    #insert usual stuff here
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter(
        'Name',  [string], $attributeCollection
    )
    # more stuff
}
begin
{
    $name = $PSBoundParamters.'Name '
}
```

This means you *get* the parameter name with Get-Help, but not the actual text. It's a horrible hack, but it gets you halfway there...

Answer (score -1):

There is a `HelpMessage`property on `System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute` which you can use to set the help text within your dynamic parameter:

```
# Create a collection of attributes
$AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

$ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
$ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
$ParameterAttribute.Position = 0
$ParameterAttribute.HelpMessage = "YOUR_HELP_MESSAGE"

# Add the attributes to the attributes collection
$AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)
```

Comment: It does not return the help message when I use ge-thelp mFunction.

Comment: try get-help mFunction -full

Comment: I do not see the help message during get-help .\script.ps1 even if I use -full.

Comment: Thats Not how get-help is supposed to work. You have to Query for a Function, Not a Script

Comment: Get-Help works fine with .PARAMETER-style help on a script.  Neither I nor my users want to recycle their shell or re-Import-Module every time we make an update to a rapidly evolving system.

Comment: See also https://powershell.org/2013/05/06/a-helpful-message-about-helpmessage/  -- i.e. the HelpMessage property is pretty useless.  I really shouldn't even need -full in any context to make this work.

Comment: @Timbo are you aware that we are talking about dynamic parameters?

Comment: Yes I am aware. I presume that dynamic and static parameters both have a ParameterAttribute member and that [HelpMessage="..."] maps to it.  I tried wrapping a function around my script logic <# .SYNOPSIS... #> function Foo { param ( ... ) DynamicParam { ... } process { ... } } and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: (Get-Command .\script.ps1).Parameters shows the dynamic parameter, but it does not appear in the auto-generated SYNTAX section nor the curated PARAMETERS section of Get-Help, -full or not.

Comment: I believe that you are incorrect in asserting that Get-Help doesn't work for scripts.  I get the exact same output when I dot-source the script containing my function-wrapped logic and Get-Help Foo as I do when I Get-Help on the unwrapped script.

Comment: It looks like dynamic parameter help only works if comment-based help is entirely missing, and that comment-based help is The Option for tying scripts to the Get-Help system.